# Negotiating a bonus

Tags: salary, bonus

I've just been offered a job at my expected salary (which may have been slightly under the market value). As there were no negotiations, I'm wondering if I asked for too little and as there were no mentions of bonus, it might be a good way to increase things without coming across as too aggressive.

How should I phrase that? Is it wise?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. He who states a figure (first) is usually at the strategic disadvantage. You might have to bite this one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ask, but it is a long-shot. Signing bonuses are rare, and used for particularly hard-to-find talent.

If they have met your salary requirements, your best bet for further negotiations is to ask for more PTO, particularly if your compensation package has less (or not more) vacation than your previous job.

Ultimately, though, there is no non-aggressive way to say: "Thanks for offering the money that I asked for, and said that I would be satisfied with. I'm ready to take the job if you just offer more money."